# Unable to unit test cloud_firestore live

Tags: unit-testing, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to write a unit test that verifies a certain number of documents exist.

This is what I have so far

```
  test('Login with no account', () async {
    Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
    final QuerySnapshot result = await _firestore
        .collection(UserFirestoreField.Collection)
        .where(UserFirestoreField.EmailAddress, isEqualTo: 'email@example.com')
        .where(UserFirestoreField.Password, isEqualTo: 'wrongpassword')
        .getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = result.documents;
    print(docs);
  });
```

The error I'm getting is

> package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 314:7 
>   MethodChannel.invokeMethod
>
> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
>   Query#getDocuments on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)

I have the android emulator running with my app started.

Every guide I've seen talks about mocking a database, I want to actually check the real database.

Any way to do this in dart/flutter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Flutter, unit and widget tests run on your host machine which does not have the native part of your firebase plugin. This is why you are getting this error.

You really should mock the database in tests but if you really want to test your app as close to how it is run by a user you would run an integration test on an emulator.

You can also use a dart based Firebase plugin or use the Firebase REST API.

You can find more about this here: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing

Comment: Any reason why I shouldn't be using the live database?

Comment: @LongTSQLFiles: Most developers feel that "Unit Tests" should run locally without infrastructure dependencies (the unit works entirely with eg mocks or test doubles or what-have-you). Some developers do test infrastructure with "Integration Tests" (their merit notwithstanding). The problem with integration testing the Firebase/Flutter platform is that authentication doesn't work in test mode. At all. It is [known issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/265) that will hopefully soon be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could JsonDecode into a local map and test the map.